# grafana on localhost failing authentication

Tags: apache, configuration, localhost, grafana

I've setup `Carbon`, `graphite` server, `postgresql` and `Graphana` on my localhost machine.

I am able to send metrics to graphite like: `echo "test.count 12`date +%s`" | nc -q0 127.0.0.1 2003` and **I can see the metric and graph in Graphite**.

some of my configs:

**/etc/grafana/grafana.ini**

```
[database]
type = postgres
host = 127.0.0.1:5432
name = grafana
user = graphite
password = mypass

[server]
protocol = http
http_addr = 127.0.0.1
http_port = 3000
domain = mygrafana.com
enforce_domain = true
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s/

[security]
admin_user = admin
admin_password = mypass
secret_key = something

...
...
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/apache2-grafana.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ServerName mygraphana.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Graphana is enabled:
`sudo a2ensite apache2-grafana`

Configured Grafana to run after boot and then start service:

```
sudo update-rc.d grafana-server defaults 95 10
sudo service grafana-server start
```

I also added my local IP to `/etc/hosts`

> 192.168.1.16    mygrafana.com

Now, when I access mygrafana.com on the browser, the grafana page loads and when I enter user: `admin` and pass `mypass` it gives me an authentication error.

the `mypass` is set on *grafana.ini* but I might be missing something, just don't know what or what else to do for debugging this issue.

Comment: The admin password when set via the ini file is set on the first run only. Does the default password: admin work?

Comment: Hey, yes, that work! password and user 'admin' gosh! many thanks, You can put this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default password for the admin user is admin. The admin password in the grafana.ini is only set the first time the Grafana server is run. You can change the password by logging in as admin and then changing it in the user settings. (It is also possible to set the password via the API using curl if you need to do it in a script)

Answer (score 3):

Now grafana provides grafana cli command to reset password

```
grafana-cli admin reset-admin-password --homepath "/usr/share/grafana" <password>
```

where you can give any password based on your choice

If this does not work as there is reported bug when this command does not come in effect then there is more concrete & accurate way to do so (make sure you are running all commands with **SUDO**) -

1. Install sqlite3

   `apt-get install sqlite3`
2. Connect to grafana.db

   `sqlite3 /var/lib/grafana/grafana.db`
3. Run update command

   `update user set password = '59acf18b94d7eb0694c61e60ce44c110c7a683ac6a8f09580d626f90f4a242000746579358d77dd9e570e83fa24faa88a8a6', salt = 'F3FAxVm33R' where login = 'admin';`
4. run `.exit`

then you should be fine to use admin as password for admin user.... It will ask you to reset your password for your choice....